# Django: annote through several multi-valued relationships

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-queryset, django-orm

Django 1.8 and 1.9, Postgres DB.

I have a `Contest` model that can have many related `Entry` objects submitted by `Users`.

```
class Contest(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Entry(models.Model):
    contest = models.ForeignKey(Contest, related_name="entries")
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

I want to get a list of all `Contest` objects, annotated with a `complete` flag indicating if a particular `user` has submitted an `Entry` for each `Contest`.

```
from django.db.models import Case, When, BooleanField, Value

user = User.objects.get(...)
contests = Contest.objects.annotate(
    complete=Case(
        When(entries__user=user, then=Value(True)),
        default=Value(False),
        output_field=BooleanField(),
    )
)
```

The expected result on `contests` would be something like this (for user1):

[image: Expected output]

But instead, I'm getting duplicate elements depending on the amount of `Entries` on each `Contest` (notice Contest 4 and 5):

[image: Actual output]

At this point, I tried adding `distinct()` to the end of the queryset, but since the new `complete` annotation is taken into account, I'm still getting duplicates for `Contest 4`.

[image: Output with distinct()]

Since I'm on Django >= 1.8 and using Postgres, I thought of using `distinct("id")`. Sadly, this sets complete to `False` in `Contest 4`.

[image: Output with distinct("id")]

And that's the part where I decided to post this question. Any pointers on how to get from the current results to the expected ones (first table)? Am I greatly overlooking something by going with the conditional annotation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add both `order_by` and `distinct` to get the result you want.

```
contests = Contest.objects.annotate(
    complete=Case(
        When(entries__user=user, then=Value(True)),
        default=Value(False),
        output_field=BooleanField(),
    )
).order_by('id', '-complete').distinct('id')
```

Please take care of the following note from the documentation of [`distinct`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#distinct)

> When you specify field names, you must provide an `order_by()` in the QuerySet, and the fields in `order_by()` must start with the fields in `distinct()`, in the same order.
>
> For example, `SELECT DISTINCT ON (a)` gives you the first row for each value in `column a`. If you don’t specify an order, you’ll get some arbitrary row.

So first order the results by `id` and then decreasing order of `complete` (*otherwise you would get rows with* `complete=False` *at the top*). And, then using `distinct('id')` retains the first rows for each `id` and removes the others.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that produces the desired results. Coincidentally, I do need to order the contests by another field (not shown in the example, let's say it's a date). I think I can get away with it by casting the queryset into a list, and the sorting there.